Python: creating af gif from multible images with different duration for each image
I am trying to create a gif using 3 different images where I specify the duration for each image.
Is there a good way to make the duration variable for each image?
Alternatively, is there a way to append an image at the end of a gif for a specified duration?
from PIL import Image


imgpath = "C:/Users/Username/Downloads/gif/"

image1 = Image.open(imgpath+"image1.png")
image2 = Image.open(imgpath+"image2.png")
flicker = Image.open(imgpath+"flicker.png")

fp_out = imgpath/"GIF.gif"


img = image1

img.save(fp=fp_out, format ='GIF', append_images=[image1, flicker, image2, flicker],
         save_all=True, duration=3000, loop=0)


Passing duration as a tuple worked, as @jasonharper suggested. But I had to pass the tuple with 5 numbers rather than 4. I ended up looking like this
img.save(fp=fp_out, format ='GIF', append_images=[image1, flicker, image2, flicker],          save_all=True, duration=(0,5000,25,170,25), loop=0)
